# JTextArea как работать с выделенным текстом

Tags: java, swing

Как работать с выделенным текстом в `JTextArea`?

Пример: пользователь выделил текст в `JTextArea` нажал на кнопку и с этим выделенным текстом что-то произошло, например он заменился на "TEST"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого подойдёт метод [`replaceSelection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#replaceSelection(java.lang.String)):

```
JButton butt = new JButton("Replace");
JTextArea area = new JTextArea();

butt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        area.replaceSelection("TEST");
    }
});
```

---

Результат работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  → [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как это давно было, но спасибо, ответа так я тогда и не дождался.